# JavaFX tab-pane styling, how to remove extra white space

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2

I'm styling JavaFX TabPane component with css and I haven't bee able to find what is actually making extra whitespace around the tabs. Have someone found the way to remove extra space from tabheader area? Picture is showing what I'm having currently.

[image: Styled tabs. Extra grey area should still be removed.]

Answer (score 0):

You can add borders and margins to JavaFX classes by setting them in [CSS style sheets](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). Actually all styling in JavaFX should be done like that.

Here is a tutorial for [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).
You will also want to look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node), where the possible CSS elements for JavaFX are explained.

What you are looking for is "-fx-padding". From the reference:

> A sets of four padding values, separated by commas. For each item in the series, a single padding value means that all padding are the same; and if a set of four padding values is specified, they are used for the top, right, bottom, and left edges of the region, in that order.

You can e.g. set the padding for all tabs by adding a style sheet to the screen:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("urlpath/to/mystylesheet.css");
```

Where "mystylesheet.css" has the following contents:

```
.tab{
   -fx-padding: 0 30 0 30;
}
```

Or you can also add a style to individual elements in code:

```
  Tab tabA = new Tab();
  tabA.setText("Tab A");
  tabA.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 30 0 30;");
  tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);
```